# A better alternative to "in order for X to"

Tags: idiomatic-language

> He can swing his arm fast enough in order for him to swim faster than
> Michael Phelps.

"In order for him to" sounds a bit too familiar and doesn't sound too idiomatic, is there a better phrase that I can use to express the same idea?

Comment: The sentence is bad grammar. "in order to" means "for the purpose of", which I don't think is the intended meaning here. I think you mean, "He can swing his arm fast enough to swim faster than Michael Phelps."

Comment: It doesn't sound 'familiar', it just makes the sentence unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: It's more natural without 'for him', but is still unlikely to be used.  Usually the 'in order to' setup requires some urge, not an existing assessment, so 'He **will have to** swing his arm fast enough in order to swim faster than MP' would sound more natural.  Is the sentence about someone who *wants to* swim faster, or someone who *already can* swim faster than Phelps?  Also, you wouldn't normally describe the swimming action as 'swinging your arms'.  After 'He can ...', 'make strokes' or 'stroke through the water' would sound better.